# convert int to datetime in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, datepicker

In my model class i have
 `public DateTime GoalDate { get; set; }`

in my view class i have

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.weightGoalDate
```

in my controller i have

```
 var newGoal = new Goal();

            newGoal.bpGoalDate = DateTime.Now ;
```

What i want is to set the Goal date to be 1 week after the current date and display in textbox when page load.

for instance when i load the page the date will be set on 8/1/2012 automatically since today is 7/25/2012

Answer (score 3):

use [`AddDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) method

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
  var newGoal=new Goal();
  newGload.GoalDate =DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
  return View(newGoal);  
}
```

from msdn,

> Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of days to the
>   value of this instance.

Comment: how do i display that in the textbox though?

Comment: use @Html.TextBoxFor helper method

Comment: like this @Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.GoalDate)?

Comment: that display nothing on textbox

Comment: is your view strongly typed to `Goal` class ? . Then it should.